# Auto completes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete

I have lots of auto completes like City, country, companies, brands, people names, etc. Now my team is currently giving each autocomplete a separate model in codeigniter. The issue i have is then each autocomplete has its own code. I want to make it templatized so there is only 1 code base for all auto completes and it pulls the autocompletes in and out dynamic.

Is it possible or is the way my team is doing it the correct way?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but your question is too vague/too complex to answer without more context and code.

Comment: Context is: Should each autocomplete (which is a table like city lookup, country lookup etc) have its own model and php file for it to work or can there be 1 auto complete library code and that can dynamically pull 0 to n number of auto completes somehow? What i am trying to achieve is minimize the number of project files, make maintainence easier and prevent touching the code if i add more auto completes because on my system almost every textfield has auto complete and i dont want hundreds of files to maintain for each auto comlete.

Answer (score 0):

Your CI models should be organized to reflect your domain, so in the case of cities, countries, companies and such, each are different entities and deserve a seperate model. More files does not mean it is less maintainable.

As for autosuggest, your model simply needs to deliver the data to a controller that will be called using Ajax. You can do the json_encoding of the data stream in the model or the controller, I prefer to use the controller.

So eventually yoiu hopefully have a single autosuggest plugin in the front-end that simply calls different controller URLs. These controllers know which model to use to get the autosuggest data.

This is a clean seperation of duties, and maintainable.